# Ionic 5 keeps reloading same page after API subscription

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

Im calling an API that contain pagination.

For pagination im using ngb-pagination.
The request for API is the page number and the response are data to be diplayed.
After calling API, when i change from page 1 to 2 its recalling twice the API.
With request page =  2 and than with request page = 1. It looks like its reloading the view again and again.

Pagination initialized with page = 1;

```js
  ionViewWillEnter()
{
  this.filterUserOntimeFunction(1)
}
```

function to change the page

```js
 onPageChange = (pageNumber) => {
    this.filterUserOntimeFunction(pageNumber);
    this.pageSize = this.itemsPerPage * (pageNumber - 1);
  };
```

function that call API

```js
filterUserOntimeFunction = (request) => {
    this.filterService.filterUserOntime(request).subscribe(data => {
      this.dataStore = data['response'];
      this.collectionSize = data["response"].length;
      this.pageSize = this.collectionSize / 5;     
    }, error => console.log('Could not load data.', error));
  }
```

code in html just display some data

```html
<div *ngIf="dataStore; else elseBlock">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row class="ion-nowrap">
        <ion-col class="text-center" size="6" *ngFor="let j of dataStore">
          <ion-card class="myCard" (click)="personSelected(j)">
            <ion-img
              [src]="j.t_path_immagine"
              style="width: max-content"
              alt="100"
            ></ion-img>
            <ion-item class="myOverlay">
              <div class="subtitle"></div>
              <ion-label class="ml-2 card-title">{{j.t_nome}}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ngb-pagination
        [collectionSize]="collectionSize"
        [(page)]="currentPage"
        [pageSize]="itemsPerPage"
        (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)"
        [maxSize]="5"
        aria-label="Default pagination"
      ></ngb-pagination>
      <ion-button (click)="logScrollEnd(dataStore.length)"
        >Load more</ion-button
      >
    </ion-grid>
  </div>

  <ng-template #elseBlock> Data is loading. Please wait </ng-template>
```

Result its like in image below[image]:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic 5 and ngb-pagination is not working as expected.
Instead version 4 is working good.

The code i had to change is to uninstall boostrap, ngx-pagination and remove

```html
<ngb-pagination
        [collectionSize]="collectionSize"
        [(page)]="currentPage"
        [pageSize]="itemsPerPage"
        (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)"
        [maxSize]="5"
        aria-label="Default pagination"
      ></ngb-pagination>
```

Instead of that have inserted below code

```html
 <pagination-controls (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)"></pagination-controls>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ion-infinite-scroll
      [disabled]="isScrollDisabled"
      threshold="100px"
      (ionInfinite)="loadMoreData($event)"
    >
      <ion-infinite-scroll-content
        loadingSpinner="bubbles"
        loadingText="Loading more data..."
      >
      </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

use this and update your pagenumber via ts file like this

```
export class XYZ{
pageNumber : number;

 ionViewWillEnter()
{ this.pageNumber = 0;
  this.filterUserOntimeFunction(this.pageNumber);
}
loadMoreData(event){ 
    this.pageNumber++ ;
    this.filterUserOntimeFunction(this.pageNumber);
}

}
```

this work's really great.

Comment: thanks but i was looking for pagination not scrolling.